# How to solve this ODE $~ y''+ (1-x^2)y = 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying desperately to solve the following differential equation;

$$ y''+ (1-x^2)y = 0 $$

I am looking for all smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ which solve this equation. I have tried everything in my power to do it, but I can't figure what would work. I realize this seems like a special case of Weber's differential equation, which has special functions as solutions. But I believe that for this particular equation there must be an elementary and elegant approach to find the solutions. What can be done?

---

**Edit:** I am looking for an analytic solution and am also interested in how to arrive at the solution.

Comment: [Kovacic's algorithm](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1984/CS-84-35.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By observation, we can find one solution in the form of

$$y_1=e^{ax^2}$$

Plug in and simplify, we get

$$(2a+4a^2x^2+1-x^2)e^{ax^2}=0\Rightarrow a=-\frac{1}2$$

So one solution is

$$y_1=e^{-\frac{1}2x^2}$$

We use reduction of order to find the second solution, for $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$

$$y_2=y_1\int^x\frac{e^{-\int P(t)~ dt}}{y_1^2}dt$$

Here, $P(x)=0$

$$y_2=y_1\int^x y_1^{-2}dt=y_1\int^x e^{t^2}~dt$$

The general solution is:

$$y=c_1\cdot e^{-\frac{1}2x^2}+c_2\cdot e^{-\frac{1}2x^2}\int^x e^{t^2}~dt$$

Answer (score 4):

$$y''+ (1-x^2)y = 0$$
$$\dfrac {y''}{y}=x^2-1$$
$y=0$ is a solution now suppose $y\ne 0$
and substitute $u=\dfrac  {y'}{y}$:
$$u'+u^2=x^2-1$$
An obvious solution of this Riccati's differential equation  is:
$$u=-x$$
$$\implies \dfrac {y'}{y}=-x$$
$$(\ln y)'=-x$$
Integrate.
$$y=Ce^{-x^2/2}$$
(You can also try to solve the Riccati's DE since you know a particular solution.)

Comment: Explain, please, how did you receive $(u'+u^2)$ from $\dfrac{y''}{y}$?

Comment: well  @VadimChernetsov  $u'=\dfrac {yy''-y'^2}{y^2}$ because of   the quotient rule since $u=\dfrac {y'}{y}$  annd $u^2 =\dfrac {y'^2}{y^2}$

Answer (score 2):

The another method exists.
$$
y''+ (1-x^2)y = 0,
\\
y''+y-{x^2}y=0,
\\
y''+xy'-xy'+y-{x^2}y=0,
\\
y''+(xy)'-x(y'+xy)=0,
\\
(y'+xy)'-x(y'+xy)=0,
\\
$$
Here we must make the substitution: $u=(y'+xy)$.
$$
u'-ux=0,
\\
\ln(u)=\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1\right),
\\
u=e^{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1\right)},
$$
After the substitution we must return to the previous parameters.
$$
(y'+xy)=e^{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1\right)},\tag{1}
$$
Characteristic equation relatively of the provided differential equation (1) will be $(y'+xy)=0$.
$$
(y'+xy)=0,
\\
\frac{dy}{y}=-xdx,
\\
\ln(y)=\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+C_2\right),
\\
y=e^{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+C_2\right)},
$$
So our general solution will be $y_1=e^{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+C_2\right)}$.
I hope that you will find the particular solution by yourself, solving the odinary differential equation $(y'+xy)=e^{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1\right)}$.